# Time/speed performance comparison of particular function

Tags: c++, performance, performance-testing

I have a c++ program (executed on CentOS) in which I have a function which do some analysis on packets coming from pcap file. I want to compare this function in terms of speed with few other functions which do same thing but with different algorithm.
In other words I want to know how fast my function does computations as compared to other functions. How can I achieve this goal?

I did two things uptill now:

- I used chrono high resolution clock to measure time for each packet
  and then taking out time average for each unique packet length.
- I used callgrind and open its output file to analyze on kcachegrind
  but the function in which I was interested is not showing up on
  kcachegrind. (it says 1543 functions skipped)

Is there any other way I can test the time performance of the three functions